# Cant redirect to jade page node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started working in node js for last few days. On an onclick ,I am calling this function which has an ajax call here.

```
function goToUser(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/users/UserPage",
        type:'get',
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            alert("working")
        }
    })
}
```

In the users.js I have given like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/UserPage',function(req,res){
      res.render("/users/UserPage");
})
```

in the UserPage.jade file, it is like this

```
h3#getHeader Helooooo
```

But its not working is there any mistake in this?
What I just want to redirect to another jade page, I used both render and redirect here.But both are not working.

My Package .json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoskin": "*"
  }
```

In  app.js

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

This is the Part where i have given those details

Comment: Can you add the dependencies from your package.json ? And where do you require jade in your node.js application ?

Comment: @Volune:I have added those details, In the user.js, I specified the UserPage,There is nothing wrong in doing like that. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it like below

```
res.render("users/UserPage");
```

instead of

```
 res.render("/users/UserPage");
```

When you say `res.render('somefolder/file)` so it searches in `views/someolder/file`. Because you are saying `res.render('/somefolder/somefile)` so it should be getting confused with `/`.

The path to file should be `{appName}/views/users/UserPage.jade`.

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/users/UserPage 500 (Internal Server Error) My error is the above one

Comment: @Krishna I didn't get what do you mean

Comment: What i meant was , I have a div here, when i click on that,i want to show another jade page. So i wrote an ajax call which will call a function inside user.js and will render UserPage.jade

Comment: What U gave was right,But in my app.js i have given an option to join the directory name there. SO i think there is no need to give like this :users/UserPage right? if i give simply like UserPage it will be ok. If there is any mistake in my guess Please answer

Comment: when I use liked that its not going to that page, when i typed like this localhost:3000/users/UserPage its extending the index thats what i want...

Comment: what option have you given, untill you won't tell me how can I know if that is right or not?

Comment: But here why its not going automatically to this page localhost:3000/users/UserPage, here i want to type again and again to get that page. Is there any method other than res.render

Comment: The was the option i gave 
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Comment: that is the way which is being used, what I know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59332/discussion-between-krishna-and-mritunjay).